# How do I measure illuminance (lux or foot-candles)?

Tags: lighting

Many years ago, someone showed me how to use a Luna Pro light meter to measure foot-candles.

I do not recall. How do I do this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Photo-SE. You were asking two completely distinct questions ("how measure foot-candles using a Luna Pro?" vs. "how to light photos in galleries?"). Please keep Questions here focused on a single topic. I have edited your question to removed the 2nd subject being asked. If you would like to ask about lighting photos in galleries, please [Ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to convert EV (exposure values to Lux and then Lux to ft. candles.

The Lux unit is metric whereas the ft. candle is English. Only the United States and Liberia are retaining the English system.

Your light meter will provide the data on exposure in EV (exposure) values.
It is easy to convert EV to Lux.

The formula is (2^Lx) * 2.5

An exit (thanks for the input) --- Converting EV to Lux: While the two values are different, an incident light meter reading can be approximately converting using the formula 2.5 x 2^EV

Example  --- If the EV reading is 6, what is the scene brilliance in Lx?
Answer :  2^6 = 64 X 2.5 = 160 Lx

Once we know scene brilliance in Lx, we can easily convert to ft. candles.
The formula Lx X 0.0929

Convert 160 Lx to ft. candles  160 X 0.0929 = 14.86 ft. Candles.

Table to convert EV to Lx and ft. candles

EV  LUX ft. candles
1 EV                    5.00 Lx                 0.46 ft. candles

2 EV                   10.00 Lx                 0.93 ft. candles

3 EV                   20.00 Lx                 1.86 ft. candles
4 EV                   40.00 Lx                 3.72 ft. candles

5 EV                   80.00 Lx                 7.43 ft. candles

6 EV                  160.00 Lx                14.86 ft. candles

7 EV                  320.00 Lx                29.73 ft. candles

8 EV                  640.00 Lx                59.46 ft. candles

9 EV                1,280.00 Lx               118.92 ft. candles

10 EV               2,560.00 Lx               237.83 ft. candles

11 EV               5,120.00 Lx               475.66 ft. candles

12 EV              10,240.00 Lx               951.33 ft. candles

13 EV              20,480.00 Lx             1,902.65 ft. candles

14 EV              40,960.00 Lx             3,805.31 ft. candles

15 EV              81,920.00 Lx             7,610.61 ft. candles

16 EV             163,840.00 Lx            15,221.23 ft. candles

17 EV             327,680.00 Lx            30,442.46 ft. candles

18 EV             655,360.00 Lx            60,884.91 ft. candles

Comment: `The formula is (2^Lx) * 2.5` should be `The formula is (2^Ev) * 2.5`